# How to use params/properties flag values when executing pig job on google dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I am executing a bash script on dataproc using pig job

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pig --cluster=<cluster_name> --region=<region> -e "sh echo hello;sh echo $foo" --properties foo=bar --params bar=baz
```

But I am not able to access the these parameters/properties inside the script